# Hash from String in Ruby: Marshal.load? (re-create the params hash from a Rails production.log)

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, hash, marshalling

I want to parse Rails production.log files and recreate the params Hash. I am stuck with the Marshal.load method, which actually expects the data to be marshalled. Well, the data is well-formed but it is a String and not in a Marshal expected format.

here is the String that i regexed out of the request from the logfile:

```
{
 "location"=>{"city"=>"München \"foo \" bar", "id"=>"462", "youtube_tags"=>""},
 "authenticity_token"=>"UHi0GCNDBPN/Ms+0bqEOl4HGvUjDRw8tNvtqVl3v0dY=",
 "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "textinput"=>""
}
```

I tried my way around this issue with

```
o=JSON.parse.gsub("=>",":"))
```

in which case i get problems with umlauts.

Is there no way to parse or load a Hash representation from a String to actual Ruby Hash structures with Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: i updated the example with escaped quotes, so the problem becomes visible - eval would not parse this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best way to do it, but ...

```
h = eval '{
            "location"=>{"city"=>"München", "id"=>"462", "youtube_tags"=>""},
            "authenticity_token"=>"UHi0GCNDBPN/Ms+0bqEOl4HGvUjDRw8tNvtqVl3v0dY=",
            "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "textinput"=>""
          }'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. of course eval works in this example -- but unfortunately there are lots of escaped quotes, so eval breaks immediately. any ideas?